# Ninject causing "Method not found: System.Reflection.MethodInfo.CreateDelegate"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, system.reflection

I'm attempting to deploy a website that uses Ninject for DI which works well locally on my development machine. When deployed to GoDaddy hosting, I get the following error:

> Method not found: 'System.Delegate System.Reflection.MethodInfo.CreateDelegate(System.Type)'.

I'm using MVC3 (4.0 Framework).

Comment: Can you please post the full stacktrace including all the inner exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually happens if you deploy a .NET Framework 4.5 build on a machine that has 4.0 installed or the other way round.